# Why Milky serum in diet rich with Triglycerides?

Tags: biochemistry, lipids

When we eat the meal rich with triglyceride our muscle or blood after seperation of the serum the color of the serum will be milky. What is causing to happen in our serum ? Milky serum (lipemic serum)

Comment: Can you quote from your source?

Comment: I read this information in the some medical cases and also an A&Q website [link](https://www.reference.com/health/causes-lipemic-serum-adf832c9ce6a522e#) . I know these are not suitable sources but i didn't understand so i wanted to ask .

Comment: (short hint) "These chylomicrons then pass into the [lacteals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacteal), forming a milky substance known as [chyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chyle)." .... [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacteal). Seemingly it is due to [Tyndall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyndall_effect) from coloidal nature of [Chylomicrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chylomicron)

Comment: Tyndall effect makes a sense but still not clear. Cause according to these informations that milky color occurs in lacteals that is a part of lymphatic system and we dont get the serum from lymphatic vessels actually we obtain the serum from the blood.